# How group by and counting RDD[Map[Array[Int],Int]]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, grouping, rdd

I have some input data as `RDD[Map[Array[String],String]]`:

```
(Map(Array[c1, a1] -> Y),
Map(Array[a1] ->Y), 
Map(Array[c1, a1] ->N),
Map[Array[a1] ->N),
Map[Array[a1] ->Y))
```

I want to group by key, value and scale each value by key. As output, I want to create an `RDD[Map[Array[String],Int]]` as follows:

```
(Map(Array[c1, a1, Y] -> 0.5),
(Map(Array[c1, a1, N] -> 0.5),
(Map(Array[a1 ,Y ] -> 0.66), 
(Map(Array[a1, N] -> 0.33))
```

I'm using Scala and Spark for bigdata.

Comment: Consdier accepting the answer if it helped you solve the problem, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/380158 :)

Answer (score 0):

Using an RDD, one way to solve this would be to use `reduceByKey` to collect a list of all values (in this case `Y` and `N`). We can then calculate the proportion of each value depending on the key.

The below solution assumes that each `Map` only have one (key,value) pair on each row (it can be extended to work for more but it's a bit more complicated).

```
rdd
  .map(m => (m.keys.head, m.values.toList))
  .reduceByKey(_ ::: _)                         // Collect a list with Ys and Ns
  .flatMap{ case(k,v) =>
    val uniqueCount = v.groupBy(identity)       // Unique values and their counts
      .mapValues(_.size) 
    val totalCount = v.size.toFloat             // Total count

    // Create return list with Maps
    uniqueCount.map{case (uniqueVal, uniqueCount) => Map((k :+ uniqueVal) -> uniqueCount / totalCount)}
}
```

Result:

```
Map(List(c1, a1, Y) -> 0.5)
Map(List(c1, a1, N) -> 0.5)
Map(List(a1, Y) -> 0.6666667)
Map(List(a1, N) -> 0.33333334)
```